# fonts in pharo missing

Tags: fonts, pharo

When I navigate to **System->Appearance->Standard fonts** and try to select a different font, a selector pops up with only two fonts in it: Accuny and Bitmap Dejavu Sans. Of course my system, Slackware, has a lot more fonts installed. Why doesn't Pharo see them?
Lunching "Update system font" doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a VM problem (no FT2Plugin installed).

You can try downloading this one: http://files.pharo.org/vm/cog

hope this helps you